# Curve Deform Modifier Behaving Strangely

Tags: transforms, parent, origin, curve-modifier, surface-deform

Blender wizards,

I've developed a curve, using a spiral, to use as the object of a deform modifier for a circle. The purpose of this is to "apply" a "sticker" to the path of this curve, allowing it to appear to be on the curve of the white spiral object.

When I first created this model, this method worked flawlessly. However, somewhere along the way I must have been destructive. The model, curves, and "stickers", were all parented to an empty, for control, which has been manipulated.

I've released the parent, applied all transforms to both the "sticker" and the curve, zeroed out the origins and cursors, but...

When I apply the curve modifier to my "sticker", and slide the X-Axis, the "sticker" not only doesn't follow the curve (seems to be offset but roughly following a spiral), but it also progressively warps its dimensions as it slides.

Does anyone have an understanding of what I've destroyed in this process, and if there's something I can do to reset this calamity?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g1P_2WhyQRYZfwg4m47EaQpezLMiLJr5/view?usp=sharing

[image: Edit mode view of the spiral/curve]

[image: Object mode view of the spiral/curve]

[image: Object mode view of sticker]

[image: Curve modifier applied to sticker, sticker moved along x-axis]

[image: Orthographic view of sticker not aligned to spiral]

Comment: Hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yes of course - I've edited the original post. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the parent (the empty called *Label Roll_GL_01.006*): Apply the scale and rotation of your empty, apply the scale and rotation of the curve, in *Edit* mode select all the curve vertices and right click > *Set Curve Radius* > type 1 and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: An absolute legend you are. I knew the parent operation was doing something. Thank you kindly moonboots.